# rails : how to set locale in elasticsearch use chewy gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, chewy-gem

I use elasticsearch by gem Chewy. and I use Globalize gem to translation.
I have a model Location, and translate attribute name of location. But chewy only update last data, don't update data with different locale.
I want to chewy update both data (with locale :en , :fr, ..)
How to set or config globalize in  elasticsearch

in file location_index.rb

```
class LocationsIndex < Chewy::Index
  settings analysis: {
    analyzer: {
      folding: {
          tokenizer: "standard",
          filter:  [ "lowercase", "asciifolding" ]
        },
      sorted: {
        tokenizer: 'keyword',
        filter: ['lowercase', 'asciifolding']
      }
    }
  }

  define_type Location do
    field :name, type: 'string', analyzer: 'standard' do
      field :folded, type: 'string', analyzer:   "folding"
    end
    field :location, type: 'geo_point', value: ->{ {lat: lat, lon: lon} }
  end

  define_type Place do
    field :name, type: 'string', analyzer: 'standard' do
      field :folded, type: 'string', analyzer:   "folding"
    end
    field :address, type: 'string', analyzer: 'standard' do
      field :address, type: 'string', analyzer: 'folding'
    end
    field :category, index: 'not_analyzed', value: ->{ category.name if category.present?}
    field :location, type: 'geo_point', value: ->{ {lat: lat, lon: lon} }
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you show your LocationIndex class? How do you setup `define_type`?

Comment: hi @Anton. i update LocationIndex above